# CRC error from PN532 NFC board when sending GetInitiatorCommand (0x88) instruction

Tags: nfc, pn532

I am using an Adafruit PN532 breakout board to emulate an NTAG213 ISO/IEC 14443-2 tag.  I have configured the board for emulation with TgInitAsTarget as follows:

[ 0x8C, 0x01,
  0x44, 0x00, 0x7B, 0x58, 0x80, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00,
  0x00 ];

in response to which I get a ReadSig request for the originality signature:

[ 0x8D, 0x00, 0x3C ]

which confirms communication with the initiator is working.  I successfully handle the request by returning the originality signature shown in part and obscured here for obvious reasons:

[ 0x90, 0x??, 0x??, 0x??, ... ]

to which I get a positive response:

[ 0x91, 0x00 ]

I then repeatedly send an explicit GetInitiatorCommand instruction at 100ms intervals (I have tried up to 250ms with no luck) in order to retrieve the next command from the initiator:

[ 0x88 ]

to each of which the PN532 responds with a CRC error:

[ 0x89, 0x02 ]

I am using the same algorithm to calculate the checksum on all these commands when I send them so I don't think my CRC is actually wrong, but to be explicit the full data frame sent to the PN532 is:

[ 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x02, 0xFE, 0xD4, 0x88, 0xA4, 0x00 ]

When I run the calculations manually this appears to have the correct CRC's for both length and data.

Incidentally if I use a completely different device as the initiator it behaves similarly - though responding initially with a Read command (0x30) - which suggests the problem is on my end.

Does the CRC error maybe apply to something else, the packets going between PN532 and the initiator perhaps?  Am I submitting instructions in the wrong order?  I admit I don't fully understand the implications of all the options in the TgInitAsTarget data set which I copied from another known good app, maybe I have set up my PN532 emulator incorrectly?  Clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Any tips as to what I'm doing wrong or how to diagnose the root cause?

Comment: I have not found a conclusive explanation for the CRC error and am abandoning the PN532 platform in favor of the PN7150 for other reasons so this question, while intriguing, is mute.